# Why is NuGet for NLog 3.1.0.0 not adding NLog.config files to its targets?

Tags: nuget, nlog

I thought that was quite an advantage of using NuGet to install NLog, yet over seven projects I have tried in my solution, none has an NLog.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your position, but the [docs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog) for the package say

> This package installs NLog.dll with includes core logging
>   functionality.
>
> For your main project also need to install "NLog Configuration"
>   package.

The NLog.Schema package used to install nlog, a default .config and the xsd but it looks like that may have changed too.

Comment: Indeed, you do also need to install the .config package.